# scala - generic unzip for HList

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have the following Scala problem:

Write a function that will take a list of HLists

```
List(23 :: “a” :: 1.0d :: HNil, 24 :: “b” :: 2.0d :: HNil)    # this is list of hlists
```

and return back HList of Lists

```
List[Int](23, 24) :: List[String](“a”, “b") :: List[Double](1.0d, 2.0d) :: HNil # this is hlist of lists
```

This is sort of like generic unzipN. Is it at all possible for arbitrary HList?

Thank you.

Comment: Wow, this is a `GroupBy` on a type level. Very interesting. Post it to the Shapeless mailing list!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve this problem, and defining a custom type class (as in Nikita's answer) is a perfectly good one. I personally find the following approach a little clearer, though. First let's make any heterogenous list made up of monoids into a monoid:

```
import shapeless._
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

implicit object hnilMonoid extends Monoid[HNil] {
  val zero = HNil
  def append(f1: HNil, f2: => HNil) = HNil
}

implicit def hconsMonoid[H: Monoid, T <: HList: Monoid] = new Monoid[H :: T] {
  val zero = Monoid[H].zero :: Monoid[T].zero
  def append(f1: H :: T, f2: => H :: T) =
    (f1.head |+| f2.head) :: (f1.tail |+| f2.tail)
}
```

I'm using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s `Monoid`, although you could pretty easily write your own—it's just a type class that witnesses that a type has a addition-like operation with an identity element. Crucially for this example lists (of anything) are monoids under concatenation, with the empty list as the identity element.

Next for a simple polymorphic function that wraps whatever you give it in a list:

```
object singleton extends Poly1 { implicit def anything[A] = at[A](List(_)) }
```

And then we tie it all together:

```
def unzipN[L <: HList, Out <: HList](hlists: List[L])(implicit
  mapper: ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[singleton.type, L, Out],
  monoid: Monoid[Out]
): Out = hlists.map(_ map singleton).suml
```

Now we can define our example:

```
val myList = List(23 :: "a" :: 1.0d :: HNil, 24 :: "b" :: 2.0d :: HNil)
```

And we're done:

```
scala> println(unzipN(myList))
List(23, 24) :: List(a, b) :: List(1.0, 2.0) :: HNil
```

With this approach most of the machinery is very general, and it's easy to get an intuition for what each step does. Consider the following simplified example:

```
val simple = List(1 :: "a" :: HNil, 2 :: "b" :: HNil)
```

Now `simple.map(_ map singleton)` is just the following:

```
List(List(1) :: List("a") :: HNil, List(2) :: List("b") :: HNil)
```

But we know how to "add" things of type `List[Int] :: List[String] :: HNil`, thanks to our monoid machinery at the top. So we can just take the sum of the list using Scalaz's `suml`, and we're done.

This is all using Shapeless 2.0, but it would look pretty similar in 1.2.

Comment: This implementation has very interesting property. I can make it work with `Monoid[ArrayBuffer]` instance with mutable `+=` operation for `append`, and the second operand of `append` is always of size 1.

Comment: I made 2 small improvements: unzipN takes singleton function as parameter now and unzipN can work on other arguments that are Functor and Foldable. `def unzipN[L <: HList, Out <: HList, FF[_] : Functor : Foldable](f: Poly1)(hlists: FF[L])(implicit
                                                            mapper: ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[f.type, L, Out],
                                                            monoid: Monoid[Out]): Out = hlists.map(_ map f).suml`

Comment: Cool! Note that `.map(...).suml` can be expressed as `.foldMap(...)`, and be careful mixing type classes like `Monoid` and side effects—one of the nice things about `Monoid` is that you can assume e.g. that the order of a reduction doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this you'll need a custom typeclass:

```
import shapeless._

trait Unzipper[ -input ]{
  type Output
  def unzip( input: input ): Output
}
object Unzipper {
  implicit def headTail
    [ head, tail <: HList ]
    ( implicit tailUnzipper: Unzipper[ List[ tail ] ]{ type Output <: HList } )
    =
    new Unzipper[ List[ head :: tail ] ]{
      type Output = List[ head ] :: tailUnzipper.Output
      def unzip( list: List[ head :: tail ] ) = 
        list.map(_.head) :: tailUnzipper.unzip(list.map(_.tail))
    }
  implicit val nil =
    new Unzipper[ List[ HNil ] ]{
      type Output = HNil
      def unzip( list: List[ HNil ] ) = HNil
    }
}

val list = List(23 :: "a" :: 1.0d :: HNil, 24 :: "b" :: 2.0d :: HNil)
println( implicitly[Unzipper[list.type]].unzip(list) )
```

Outputs:

```
List(23, 24) :: List(a, b) :: List(1.0, 2.0) :: HNil
```

Comment: How do I get back to HList from `implicitly[Unzipper[list.type]].unzip(list)`?

Comment: You'll need another typeclass, which is an inverse. With the code above I believe you have enough information on how to do that on your own. Otherwise start a new thread because it is another question and you have answers to your original one.

Comment: haha. I'd rather use Travis Brown's implementation for few reasons: