# Is there some extended version of unzip in scala which works for any List[n-tuple] instead of just List[pairs] like Unzip?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

If I have a list of 3-tuples I want three separate lists. Is there some better way than this:

```
(listA, listB, listC) = (list.map(_._1), list.map(_._2). list.map(_._3))
```

which can work for any n-tuple?

**EDIT:**  Though for three unzip3 exists of which I was unaware while writing this question, is there way to write a function for getting in general n lists?

Comment: Check out  `unzip3`

Comment: The problem with trying to generalize tuples is that there is no type `Tuple`.  Now only is `Tuple2` a different type from `Tuple3`, `Tuple2[Int,Int]` is a different type from `Tuple2{Int,Char]`.  As soon as you try to generalize tuple handling, like using `productIterator`, you start to loose valuable type information on the tuple elements.

Comment: Would you be interested in a Shapeless-based solution? That would definitely be possible (see e.g. [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21442473/334519)).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
scala> val array = Array((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
array: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] = Array((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))

scala> val tripleArray = array.unzip3
tripleArray: (Array[Int], Array[Int], Array[Int]) = (Array(1, 4, 7),Array(2, 5,8),Array(3, 6, 9))
```

Comment: I was unaware of unzip3, it serves my purpose for 3-tuples but is there some general function or some way to write a general function ?