# How to check if types are Tuple in compile time

Tags: scala

I have the following case class:

```
case class MyClass[A,B](a:A, b:B)
```

I want to add a function like unzip to `MyClass` so if `A` and `B` are Tuple types then I want to extract them like the following:

```
val item = MyClass[(Int,String), (Int,String)]((2,"two"), (3,"three"))
val item_left = MyClass(item.a._1, item.b._1)
val item_right = MyClass(item.a._2, item.b._2)
```

How should I do that and check the type for tuple in compile time? I don't want to define it in the companion object and I want it to be a function in `MyClass`. I know that I can define an `implicit` function but is it the only way?

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442473/scala-generic-unzip-for-hlist#21444327

Comment: Check out type constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `<:<` type class to prove that `A` and `B` are sub-types of `Tuple2`, so that you can decompose them. That is, we can write an `unzip` method to have the some free type parameters that would be the decomposed ordinate types (call them `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, and `B2`). Then, we require evidence that `A <:< (A1, A2)` and `B <:< (B1, B2)`. If the sub-typing relationship is true, the compiler will find instances of these type classes, which we can use to finalize the conversion. That is, `A <:< (A1, A2)` extends the function `A => (A1, A2)`.

```
case class MyClass[A, B](a: A, b: B) {
  def unzip[A1, A2, B1, B2](implicit
      ev1: A <:< (A1, A2),
      ev2: B <:< (B1, B2)
    ): (MyClass[A1, A2], MyClass[B1, B2]) = {
    val (a1, a2) = ev1(a)
    val (b1, b2) = ev2(b)
    (MyClass(a1, a2), MyClass(b1, b2))
  }
}
```

In action:

```
scala> MyClass((2, "two"), (3, "three")).unzip
res6: (MyClass[Int,String], MyClass[Int,String]) = (MyClass(2,two),MyClass(3,three))
```

For non-tuples:

```
scala> MyClass(1, 2).unzip
<console>:14: error: Cannot prove that Int <:< (A1, A2).
       MyClass(1, 2).unzip
                     ^
```

Comment: My semantics of what values go where might not be exactly what you want, but you can just re-arrange them to fit your requirements.

Comment: where can I find doc related to <:< and what do you call it?

Comment: even there is no need to explicitly use ev1(a), a._1 and a._2 work because of that implicit functions

Comment: Note that in the collections library, instead of `Traversable[A]#unzip[A1, A2]` taking an `A <:< (A1, A2)` (requiring that `A` actually *be* a tuple), it takes `A => (A1, A2)`, which relaxes the restriction so that only an implicit conversion to a tuple must be present.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is excellent. You could also go a much simpler route if you're willing to require that A and B are sub-types of Product in the declaration of your case class:

```
case class MyClass[A <: Product, B <: Product](a:A, b:B) {
  def item_left = (a.productIterator.toList(0), b.productIterator.toList(0))
  // etc.
}
```

Now, you can write:

```
val x = MyClass((2,"two"), (3,"three"))
x.item_left
```

which results in:

```
(2,3)
```

of type (Any,Any).

I suggest this alternative only because it was unclear to me just how complex you're willing to be. I hope not to elicit any down votes ;)